# gnu make: how to stop and exit when errors occur in for loop make

Tags: makefile

I use 'for' loop to make subdirectories,but when some errors occur when make in subdirectory,it continues to make the next directory,can i stop when errors occur 'make' in subdirectory?

```
all :
    for i in $(SUBDIRS); do make -C $$i dll; done;
                ||
make[1]: *** [bd_snmp.o] error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ping/work/svnsocserv/src/bd_snmp'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ping/work/svnsocserv/src/bd_snmp_proxy'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, just add something to your shell script that checks:

```
all:
        for i in $(SUBDIRS); do $(MAKE) -C $$i dll || exit 1; done
```

(note ALWAYS use `$(MAKE)` to recursively invoke sub-makes, never `make`).

This is not a great method though, because while it does exit immediately when a sub-make fails it doesn't obey the make `-k` option to keep going.

Comment: thanks,it works properly.  I can use .phony to implement this.`.PHONY : $(SUBDIRS) ...